# For password box Jaws reader reads "password edit password edit password edit"

Tags: uwp, jaws-screen-reader

I have an UWP applicaion with a password box inside it.
I have JAWS 2020 reader install in my system.
For the password box the JAWS reader reads "password edit password edit password edit".
Is there any way to make the JAWS reader read the password box only once i.e "password edit"

Comment: I don't have a solution, but just for documentation: this issue occurs in XAML Islands apps as well and it's reproducible in the [XAML Controls Gallery](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/xaml-controls-gallery/9msvh128x2zt?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) app (a UWP app).

Comment: In case it's a XAML bug, I filed it here: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6431